# Linq to XML infanticide - Is there a simple expedient way to promote grandchildren to replace children?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Consider the following snippet

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var family = XDocument.Parse("<p><c><g/></c></p>");

        var usurper = family.Root.Descendants("g");
        family.Root.Element("c").Remove();
        family.Root.Add(usurper);

        Console.WriteLine(family.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output I get is `@"<p />"` but I would like `@"<p><g/></p>"`. I can see why it happens and, there is a justice to it but, its not the output I need.

If I change the the order of the lines to

```
        var usurper = family.Root.Descendants("g");
        family.Root.Add(usurper);
        family.Root.Element("c").Remove();
```

a circular relationship is set up and the remove eventualy causes an [OutOfMemoryException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx).

Is there a simple, expedient way to make this work?

**EDIT**

The fix I actually implemented was

```
        var usurper = family.Root.Descendants("g").Single();
        family.Root.Element("c").Remove();
        family.Root.Add(usurper);
```

Excuse my blushes.

Comment: It's worth voting up for the title alone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this instead

```
var usurper = family.Root.Descendants("g").ToList();
```

You have to force the enumeration to yield a result due to lazy evaluation, otherwise you get an empty result.

Comment: Was just running Jodrell's code, then made the change you suggested. It worked for me.

Comment: Yep, I actually used `Single()`, same effect, will accept soon.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call `usurper.Remove()` before adding it to the Root element.  Without this step usurper will always be a descendant of the "c" element and so when "c" gets removed so will the usurper.